# Best and safe way to conect Arduino and Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, usb

I'm developing an application that communicates with **Arduino** (*Arduino Uno*), I used two ways to communicate so far, via :

**1.** USB (I used the usb-serial-for-android and Physicaloid libraries) and

**2.** Bluetooth, sending and receiving data.

Via **Bluetooth** was a little slow and sometimes the information was simply not sent or received, the **USB** communication sending data was pretty fast, but still, sometimes the connection does not open, and it's very random, run the application and USB connection does not open, close the application, run again and the connection open, have not tried connecting via **Wifi**.

My question is this, what is the ideal and safest way to perform connection with **Arduino**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth connection is best, because HC05 adapters are dirt cheap and those use UART for communication (the same as com- port )

Comment: Thanks for the comment.